# Is it possible to write vlookup functions in Google's connected sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

So there is a requirement to build tables and charts in google sheets with data in bigquery.
The data can be brought in to google sheets using **connected sheets**. Is it possible to use connected sheets like normal spreadsheets with all the functionalities? Specifically is it possible to write vlookup functions in connected sheets data?

The only resource I could find on the internet is this tutorial video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rkimIhnLKGI.  In this video, I see that in connected sheets there are no row and column reference available like in normal spreadsheets. Is it possible to show the row and column reference? Is it possible to write cell references in functions? Is it possible to write vlookup functions in connected sheets?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.
I got a chance to work with connected sheets, they don't have the functionalities of a normal spreadsheet.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rkimIhnLKGI, This video pretty much shows all the features of connected sheets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an indirect method to accomplish that.

Use the extract function to create a new sheet and don't set any condition. Then you could use that new sheet with any function you want.

However, there is a 25000-row limitation. So if you want to process a large table, you may have to connect your sheet back to BigQuery and do the ETL on the BigQuery side.

I hope that helps you well!